# IIS express deploy application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have visual studio 2010 at home and have developed a web application. I am now at another computer in another location. All I have is the project folder on my usb drive and all this computer has installed is IIS express. Is there any way I can somehow get my web application up and running?

Comment: Related post - [Creating virtual directories in IIS express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8735713/465053)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that you have all the files needed to run the web application in the project folder, you should be able to create the site in IIS Express and launch it.

Here's what you will probably need to add to the IIS Express configuration file. The file is typically located in "C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config".

Below, you will need to change the path to the website and make sure that you bind to it correctly. You might need to change the port number if it conflicts with any other websites that you want to keep.

```
<sites>
    <site name="MyWebsite" id="1" serverAutoStart="false">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="<USB Drive>:\<FolderToMyWebsite>" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
    </site>
<sites>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

Examples:
port = 1111

local_ip_address = 192.168.1.1 - local network ip address where the webpage is stored

Step 1:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://local_ip_address:port/ user=Everyone
```

Step 2:

```
<bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:port:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="local_ip_address:port:" />
</bindings>
```

Step 3:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IIS Express (non-SSL)" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=port
```

found solution on comments here:
http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx