# Where is IIS Express 7.5 wwwroot Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

Using Windows 7 I have installed the IIS Express 7.5 but I cant find where is the `wwwroot` directory on my system! There is no "`inetpub`" folder on my C drive as well.
Can you please let me know where I can put a file like hello.aspx file to be run?

Thanks

Comment: Related post - [Where is the IIS Express install directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23314928/465053)

Answer (score 17):

By first-hand experience and also by [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929315), usually IISExpress holds a directory with its own *data* files at: `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress`.

There you can find the default directories for each web site log files (`Logs\` and `TraceLogFiles\`) and especially you can find all web sites configurations in file `config\applicationhost.config`. That one has a `<sites>` section with a `<site>` node for each website created.

For each website, its `<virtualDirectory>` node specifies actual root location in `physicalPath` attribute:

```xml
<site name="YourWebSiteName" id="12345">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Physical\path\to\your\website\root"/>
  </application>
  ...
</site>
```

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015 and later the path to applicationhost.config is at `<solutionDir>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

Answer (score 7):

> C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\My Web Sites\web-Site1

One simple way to test is just key in a test file in your site root, e.g.
http://localhost:1714/test.txt

System will throw a 404 error, in the "Detailed Error Information" section, system will show the "physical path" the server is trying to retrive the file. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is in your home directory. Something like c:\Users\<yourname>\Documents\IISExpress

Comment: thanks ema , there are three folders there as config, logs, and TraceLogfiles. So where should I put the file? and How can I see the file in browser?

Comment: Actually there isn't a default folder for that, you can put your file where you prefer and execute the IISExpress so that it points to your folder: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

you will see a location like below path

> C:\Users\YOURUSERSNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

> But where is the global directory for IIS Express? Quick answer is
>   that there is not one.  IIS Express is very much directory based. 
>   That being said, the 2 solutions I have been able to work out are:
>
> 1. Add the group of files to your root path of your web site
> 2. Create a virtual directory in IIS Express’ applicationHost.config file for the location of your global files

[More details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/01/08/a-global-directory-for-iis-express.aspx)