# Where is the IIS Express install directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have recently started an asp.net tutorial, and I want to test my page that I made with WebMatrix. How ever, there's an error:

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

So it suggests to Enable directory browsing and go to the IIS Express install directory and run a command.

So where is this located exactly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc730918(v=ws.10) 
Admin cmd prompt> `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true`

Comment: Related post - [Where is IIS Express 7.5 wwwroot Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21946074/465053)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The user Data files are present here:

```
C:\Users\[username]\Documents\IISExpress
```

If that's the error. Then you might have got the error **404.13** (*Forbidden*) on your browser.

You can try to edit the **web.config** file and add this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

This would allow the server to read the files and process them. This is a server settings error. And I think this might help you out.

**Update**

As suggested by [jamiebarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222090/jamiebarrow), you can get to that directory directly using the following path in your Windows File Explorer,

```
%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress
```

Comment: So it says: Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.

But it doesn't recognize the command appcmd

Comment: It is still a server allowance error. Here is a microsoft technet post: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx Do read it :) It would further guide you...

Comment: This answer solved my final problem!!! I couldn't run anything. I ran the appcmd it told me to run, I set windows authentication=true and anonymous authentication=false. Those 3 actions allowed me to see and traverse directories. This answer though allowed me to actually LOAD my pages. Thank you!!!

Comment: Sure thing, also it seems that newer versions of Visual Studio use a `.vs` folder at the same level as the project/solution where there is also an application host config file.

Answer (score 31):

My directory is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express
```

Comment: same here for a Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2017 installation.

Answer (score 3):

Locate the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress\<Your version>
```

and parameter "`InstallPath`".

Answer (score 0):

☢ ☣ ⚠ If you are using OneDrive with Document Sync check the folder:

```
C:\Users\[your-account]\OneDrive\Documentos\IISExpress\config
```

The common way on `%userprofile%\documents\IISExpress` said from @Afzaal sadly not works for this case (OneDrive)

Also, remenber to make the folder always on the computer (right click on folder... onedrive option)