# issue with iis express port number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

Whenever i setup a site using iis express in localhost, it automatically creates the address as `http://localhost:80/901`.

But i have originally given the url as `http://localhost:901` when i have setup the project in the iis express section of the properties.

i am redirecting from localhost:904 (iis express hosted site) to localhost:80/901 (iis express hosted site) and i couldn't open localhost:80/901 and giving the below error **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, MapRequestHandler (Error Code 0x80070002)**

How to overcome this problem? Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: `This url is giving problem when we do redirection in MVC` what do you mean?

Comment: i am redirecting from http://localhost:904 (iis express hosted site) to http://localhost:80/901 (iis express hosted site) and i couldn't open http://localhost:80/901 and giving the below error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, MapRequestHandler (Error Code 0x80070002)

Comment: I'm very unclear on what you are trying to achieve and what is your issue...what is `localhost:80/901` and why are you trying to redirect from `localhost:904` to `localhost:80/901`?

Comment: localhost:904 and localhost:80/901 are two different mvc projects hosted in iis express. programatically i am redirecting from 904 to 901.

Comment: And what is localhost:80/901 giving you without the redirect?

Comment: it is giving the same error. Can i have http://localhost:901 instead of http://localhost:80/901? i don't why iis express by default add this 80 port when i create a virtual directory :(

Comment: port 901 is my startup project.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using iis express? if yes, have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735713/creating-virtual-directories-in-iis-express ?

Comment: if i have changed anything on the applicationhost.config file, i am getting the error unable to start the iis express error.
I am trying to change the below binding from 80 to different number , but iis express couldn't launch after i change the default port.

Comment: <site name="WebSiteWithVirtualDirectory" id="7">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\temp\website1" />
   </application>
   <application path="/901" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\temp\website1" />
   </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost" />
   </bindings>
</site>

Comment: Any help on this issue will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed port 80 in iis and so iis express is taking the port 80 which is the confusion. After i closed the visual studio and add port 80 to the iis and port 80 dependency have been removed from iis express. Now i got the port as `http://localhost:901/`