# Run Web Service using IIS Express without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-express

I have created asmx web service in PC1. Now I have coped this project to some other PC2. I have installed only IIS Express and .NET Framework.

I want to run web service in PC2 using IIS Express. Is it possible or not?
Thanks!!

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735713/creating-virtual-directories-in-iis-express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the **IIS Express** folder in the C:\Program (x86) folder there's the **appcmd.exe**. First you need to add a virtual directory with the follwoing command:

```
appcmd add vdir /app.name:<site_name>/ /path:/<virtual_directory> /physicalPath:<physical_location>
```

If there is no site you can add one by yourself:

```
appcmd add site /name:SITENAME /id:2 /physicalPath:C:\PHYSICAL_PATH /bindings:http/*:8080
```

If you want to install the Service on the Default Web Site (if there is one) you can use the following:

```
vdir /app.name:"Default Web Site"/ /path:/service /physicalPath:C:\PHYSICAL_PATH
```

Comment: Claudio, but port number of web site in my PC1 is "9090", will it work with port "8080" in PC2?? Thanks

Comment: If the existing site listens to port 9090 you should type 9090. Mine is just an example. But it's possible to configure each open port

Comment: Claudio, ok thanks brother!! Do I have to change configuration in application.config file?? Thanks for your time.

Comment: First code of adding virtual directory, that you showed, can you tell me about "path"?  Will it be static? I understood the physical path.

Comment: And in the second code what about the value of "id"? @Claudio

Comment: it must be an id which isn't used yet. Usually there's a standard site with the id 1. So 2 should be free.

Comment: Ok brother, last one thing can you tell me?? What about "path" and "physical path" keywords? Thanks man @Claudio

Comment: Physical Path is the path to the folder were you're application is. Path is virtual and this is the path were you can access your service. For example: **localhost:9090/service**. Or if you type / as the path you can access your service via: **localhost:9090**

Comment: Ok, All I understood very well, so path and phsical path  keywords are just for example. Is it right? @Claudio

Comment: Hello brother, I am not able to launch appcmd.exe from IIS Express. Whenever I launch it, it closes automatically within a second. What to do? Thanks @Claudio

Comment: Change the directory in your console to the folder where appcmd is.

Comment: Means copy the project folder to the IIS express folder? Is it so? @Claudio

Comment: No. Just change directory in your console to the directory where appcmd.exe is. On my pc it would be teh command: cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express". After that you can call the appcmd command.

Comment: I am really sorry but I m not getting what are you trying to say? @Claudio

Comment: Or type instead of appcmd: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" or whatever the path is on your computer

Comment: I understand, my path is also the same one, but I am not able to launch appcmd.exe, how do I type? Claudio

Comment: I am trying open appcmd.exe directly but doesn't opening. It opens and closes within a second.

Comment: Ohh, means through command prompt, right? I thought these all I have to type in appcmd. Thanks @Claudio

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.

Steps for check:

1. Whether that system is connected with LAN.
2. You have to Set the IP address for PC2 in Edit Bindings(IIS)

Comment: are you talking of applicationhost.config ? Thanks