# MVC Routing not working for particular value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route configuration

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "catProducts",
            url: "Description/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProductDetail" }
        );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Products2",
            url: "Category/{action}/{cat}/{subcat}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", subcat = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default1",
            url: "{controller}/{action}"

        );
```

When I am trying

http://localhost/B2BWebSite/Description/ProductDetail/3

it's somtime redirect right but sometime goes to login page

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific route defined for `B2BWebSite`. Hence when you go to `http://localhost/B2BWebSite/Description/ProductDetail/3` it checks for default route and your `Default route` is `Account/Login` as below. Which is why it goes to login page.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}
            );
```

Regarding, you question about sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't; probably has something to do with login information in the session. If user is logged in, it might not go to login page.

Comment: B2BWebSite is virtual directory

Comment: In IIS, choose your virtual directory and `Convert to Application.`

Comment: Thanks for quick response but it is in visual studio

Comment: That's a different configuration question. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735713/creating-virtual-directories-in-iis-express)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify id in the first route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "catProducts",
        url: "Description/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProductDetail", id= UrlParameter.Optional  }
    );
```