# Visual Studio 2015 add virtual directory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express, virtual-directory

I have a web project in VS2015 (using IIS Express) and need to add a virtual directory for files that can be downloaded but are created by another process.  I have added an entry to my applicationhost.config file as shown below.  Whenever I start my server and go directly to a file at the location I receive a 404 in the IIS Express log.

```
<site name="CustomerPortal" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Dev\WebApps\CustomerPortal\src\CustomerPortal\wwwroot" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/WebReports" physicalPath="\\backup03\WebReports" />
    </application>

    <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49373:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Is there something different in VS2015 to add a virtual directory like this?

I am editing the config file in my project dir/.vs/config/applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 3):

For VS.Net 2015:

1.- Open the file applicationhost.config located in the following path:

> {your_solution_folder}\.vs\config\

2.- Search for the tag "sites" and find the tag for the project you want to create the virtual directory.

3.- Add the following lines:

```
<application path="/{your_virtual_directory_name}" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="{your_physical_path}" />
</application>
```

It will be something like the following:
[image]

Comment: The console shows an error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

See: [Creating virtual directories in IIS express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735713/creating-virtual-directories-in-iis-express) and [How to configure a different virtual directory for web site project with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38756986/how-to-configure-a-different-virtual-directory-for-web-site-project-with-visual)

The key is to add a root application (path= "/") and then your application.

Answer (score 0):

My problem

- VS2015
- Web Application with HTML file (no ASPX file)
- single DLL on `bin` directory
- `bin\Resources` full of js files

Html file is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wisej.SimpleDemo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Resources/findByQxh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Each js file was set to `Content` and `Copy always` and indeed it was on `bin\Resources` folder. But no way to get the `Javascript` file loaded, even after enabling the virtual directory on the `{your_solution_folder}\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file.

The `bin\Resources` was full of js files but the `\Resources` folder in the project was empty, because all js files were links to files on another project.

Steps

1) Remove all the linked files from the project `\Resources` folder.

2) Copy all the js files to the project `\Resources` folder.

3) Add all js files with build action `None` and `Do not copy`

4) Remove changes to `{your_solution_folder}\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` to be sure this was a true solution

All went smoothly. Why?

On Web Applications the true root is the project folder, where the `Web.config` is. So `http://localhost/Resources` refers to the project `\Resources` folder.